# Use 2nd OpenWRT router as DNS provider

Tags: networking, router, dns, openwrt

Last week the WiFi on my WNDR3700 died. It's running openWrt Chaos Calmer which I was very content with, especially since it was running my adblock script. This prevented me from having to install adblock programs on numerous devices and made surfing a lot safer.

I've now bought a Netgear R7000 as my new router, however I'm not going to install custom firmware on it due to a loss of power.

Would there be any way to wire my old WNDR3700 to the R7000 and let the WNDR3700 process the DNS requests?

I've tried Google, but didn't really came up with something that fit my situation.

Comment: [It isn't clear the reason you wouldn't just put OpenWRT on the Netgear R7000](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/hwdata/netgear/netgear_r7000)

Answer (score 0):

You can run whatever you want/are able to build/that will fit on your hardware on OpenWRT, it's Linux.  Of course it is easiest to install from the available packages - most routers do not have enough memory to compile software and you would have to cross-compile software for the CPU if you wanted to do that in most cases (though if your WNDR3700 has 128MB of flash you might not have problems compiling directly on it).

As far as a DNS server - there's at the very least `bind-server` and `bind-tools` available for OpenWRT that you can use - if you install those, make sure you have enough space and read [this](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/dns.bind).  You'll have to set up forwarding to your ISP or other DNS servers and edit your own zone files.  I'm sure there are others - look through the packages on the OpenWRT site.

Easiest way to put it on your network is connect an Ethernet cable to one of the LAN ports to another LAN port on your actual router.  You should reset all firewall and VLAN settings before doing this, and disable DHCP.  Use the OpenWRT web interface to assign an IP on the LAN side to the unit, and tell your other systems to use that IP as their DNS server.